# Почему многопоточный код работает медленнее?

Tags: python

У меня есть задача, в которой нужно распараллелить вычисление одной и той же функции (она одновременно считается на разных потоках, но с одинаковыми входными параметрами). Написал c помощью библиотеки threading таким образом:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=calcIntegral, args=(a,b,n)) 
t2 = threading.Thread(target=calcIntegral, args=(a,b,2*n))

integral_n  = calcIntegral(a,b,n) # instead .start()
integral_2n = calcIntegral(a,b,2*n)
```

Но, почему-то код работает столько же. Вангую, что надо было делать t1.start() и t2.start(), но при этом код работает медленнее, чем однопоточный.

Сейчас пробовал модуль multiprocessing с простым кодом:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def add(q,a,b):
    q.put(a+b)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    start_time = time.time()
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    q = mp.Queue()
    p1 = mp.Process(target=add, args=(q,3,4))
    p1.start()
    p2 = mp.Process(target=add, args=(q,2,3))
    p2.start()
    print(q.get()+q.get())
    p1.join()
    p2.join()


    print ("%.20f" % (time.time()-start_time))
```

и еще написал однопоточную версию:

```
import time

def add(a,b):
   return a+b



if __name__ == '__main__':
start_time = time.time()

print(add(2,3)+add(3,4))
print ("%.20f" % (time.time()-start_time))
```

В итоге получилось, что:
однопоточная :

```
$ python3 stuffOne.py 
12
0.00005769729614257812
```

`
многопроцессорная:

```
$ python3 stuff.py 
12
0.00005984306335449219
```

Почему так?

Comment: GIL. Читаем здесь: https://habrahabr.ru/post/149420/

Comment: Использовать модуль [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: старайтесь ограничиваться одной проблемой на вопрос (чтобы ваш вопрос был более полезен будущим посетителям). Например, вопрос про multiprocessing лучше задать отдельно.

Comment: Помимо прочего, измерения времени порядка 10^(-5) секунд нерепрезентативны. Делайте тесты, которые длятся хотя бы несколько секунд.

Answer (score 1):

Писать `t1 = threading.Thread(target=calcIntegral, args=(a,b,n))` **бесполезно**, если вы никогда не вызываете `t1.start()`. Ваш код `integral_n  = calcIntegral(a,b,n)` исполняется  **в том же**  (главном) потоке, а не в новом потоке.

Допустим вы убрали вызовы `calcIntegral()` из главного потока и вызвали `.start()` как положено, тогда замедление может быть вызвано GIL: *В CPython только один поток может исполнять чистый Питон-код в то же время*, поэтому если `calcIntegral()` не отпускает GIL (как это может делать код из `numpy`, `lxml`, `regex` пакетов и практически любой блокирующий I/O код в интерпретаторе), то производительность не улучшится.

Если необходимо исполнять CPU-bound код параллельно, то либо используйте библиотеки, которые отпускают GIL во время вычислений либо используйте отдельные процессы (`multiprocessing`, `concurrent.futures`) вместо потоков.